# why in delphi the interface of objective-c NSObject is partial?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

In delphi we have the code below :

```
 // Base Cocoa NSObject
  NSObjectClass = interface(IObjectiveCClass)
    ['{84CDD025-E02A-4128-B1AC-35A7A5A4643B}']
    procedure cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(target: Pointer); cdecl;
  end;
  NSObject = interface(IObjectiveCInstance)
    ['{C8CC567E-50C3-461C-BAA7-AD96D2CDC5C6}']
    procedure retain; cdecl;
    procedure release; cdecl;
    function retainCount: NSUInteger; cdecl;
    function isKindOfClass(cls: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl;
    function isMemberOfClass(cls: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl;
    procedure performSelector(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer; afterDelay: NSTimeInterval); cdecl;
    procedure performSelectorOnMainThread(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer; waitUntilDone: Boolean;
      modes: NSArray); cdecl;
    function respondsToSelector(aSelector: SEL): Boolean; cdecl;
  end;
  TNSObject = class(TOCGenericImport<NSObjectClass, NSObject>) end;
```

and the full declaration like below is deactivated, between (* and *)

```
(*  Use hand-coded NSObject instead of this.
  NSObjectClass = interface(IObjectiveCClass)
    ['{F9BFF4FF-EAB6-49D8-8577-A6933CA06436}']
    {class} function accessInstanceVariablesDirectly: Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function alloc: Pointer; cdecl;
    {class} function allocWithZone(zone: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
    {class} function automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key: NSString): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} procedure cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(aTarget: Pointer); cdecl; overload;
    {class} function classFallbacksForKeyedArchiver: NSArray; cdecl;
    {class} function conformsToProtocol(protocol: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function copyWithZone(zone: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function description: NSString; cdecl; overload;
    {class} procedure initialize; cdecl;
    {class} function instanceMethodForSelector(aSelector: SEL): IMP; cdecl;
    {class} function instanceMethodSignatureForSelector(aSelector: SEL): NSMethodSignature; cdecl;
    {class} function instancesRespondToSelector(aSelector: SEL): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isSubclassOfClass(aClass: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key: NSString): NSSet; cdecl;
    {class} procedure load; cdecl;
    {class} function mutableCopyWithZone(zone: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function new: Pointer; cdecl;
    {class} function resolveClassMethod(sel: SEL): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function resolveInstanceMethod(sel: SEL): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} procedure setVersion(aVersion: NSInteger); cdecl;
    {class} function version: NSInteger; cdecl;
  end;
  NSObject = interface(IObjectiveCInstance)
    ['{E4D50F26-32F2-4093-BE8E-6D328FF21945}']
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; cachedResponseIsValid: NSCachedURLResponse); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; didCancelAuthenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; didFailWithError: NSError); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; didLoadData: NSData); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; didReceiveResponse: NSURLResponse; cacheStoragePolicy: NSURLCacheStoragePolicy); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocol(protocol: NSURLProtocol; wasRedirectedToRequest: NSURLRequest; redirectResponse: NSURLResponse); cdecl; overload;
    procedure URLProtocolDidFinishLoading(protocol: NSURLProtocol); cdecl;
    procedure addObserver(observer: NSObject; forKeyPath: NSString; options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions; context: Pointer); cdecl;
    procedure archiver(archiver: NSKeyedArchiver; didEncodeObject: Pointer); cdecl; overload;
    function archiver(archiver: NSKeyedArchiver; willEncodeObject: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    procedure archiver(archiver: NSKeyedArchiver; willReplaceObject: Pointer; withObject: Pointer); cdecl; overload;
    procedure archiverDidFinish(archiver: NSKeyedArchiver); cdecl;
    procedure archiverWillFinish(archiver: NSKeyedArchiver); cdecl;
    function attemptRecoveryFromError(error: PPointer; optionIndex: NSUInteger): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    procedure attemptRecoveryFromError(error: PPointer; optionIndex: NSUInteger; delegate: Pointer; didRecoverSelector: SEL; contextInfo: Pointer); cdecl; overload;
    function autoContentAccessingProxy: Pointer; cdecl;
    function autorelease: Pointer; cdecl;
    function awakeAfterUsingCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder): Pointer; cdecl;
    function beginContentAccess: Boolean; cdecl;
    procedure cache(cache: NSCache; willEvictObject: Pointer); cdecl;
    procedure cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl;
    function conformsToProtocol(aProtocol: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function connection(connection: NSURLConnection; canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didCancelAuthenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didFailWithError: NSError); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didReceiveData: NSData); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didReceiveResponse: NSURLResponse); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didSendBodyData: NSInteger; totalBytesWritten: NSInteger; totalBytesExpectedToWrite: NSInteger); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; didWriteData: Int64; totalBytesWritten: Int64; expectedTotalBytes: Int64); cdecl; overload;
    function connection(connection: NSURLConnection; needNewBodyStream: NSURLRequest): NSInputStream; cdecl; overload;
    function connection(connection: NSURLConnection; willCacheResponse: NSCachedURLResponse): NSCachedURLResponse; cdecl; overload;
    function connection(connection: NSURLConnection; willSendRequest: NSURLRequest; redirectResponse: NSURLResponse): NSURLRequest; cdecl; overload;
    procedure connection(connection: NSURLConnection; willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl; overload;
    procedure connectionDidFinishDownloading(connection: NSURLConnection; destinationURL: NSURL); cdecl;
    procedure connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection); cdecl;
    procedure connectionDidResumeDownloading(connection: NSURLConnection; totalBytesWritten: Int64; expectedTotalBytes: Int64); cdecl;
    function connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage(connection: NSURLConnection): Boolean; cdecl;
    procedure continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl;
    function copy: Pointer; cdecl;
    function copyWithZone(zone: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    function countByEnumeratingWithState(state: NSFastEnumerationState; objects: Pointer; count: NSUInteger): NSUInteger; cdecl;
    procedure dealloc; cdecl;
    function debugDescription: NSString; cdecl;
    function description: NSString; cdecl; overload;
    function dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys: NSArray): NSDictionary; cdecl;
    procedure didChange(changeKind: NSKeyValueChange; valuesAtIndexes: NSIndexSet; forKey: NSString); cdecl;
    procedure didChangeValueForKey(key: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure didChangeValueForKey(key: NSString; withSetMutation: NSKeyValueSetMutationKind; usingObjects: NSSet); cdecl; overload;
    procedure discardContentIfPossible; cdecl;
    procedure doesNotRecognizeSelector(aSelector: SEL); cdecl;
    procedure encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder); cdecl;
    procedure endContentAccess; cdecl;
    function exceptionDuringOperation(operation: SEL; error: NSCalculationError; leftOperand: NSDecimalNumber; rightOperand: NSDecimalNumber): NSDecimalNumber; cdecl;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldCopyItemAtPath: NSString; toPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldCopyItemAtURL: NSURL; toURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldLinkItemAtPath: NSString; toPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldLinkItemAtURL: NSURL; toURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldMoveItemAtPath: NSString; toPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldMoveItemAtURL: NSURL; toURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fm: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSDictionary): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; copyingItemAtPath: NSString; toPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; copyingItemAtURL: NSURL; toURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; linkingItemAtPath: NSString; toPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; linkingItemAtURL: NSURL; toURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; movingItemAtPath: NSString; toPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; movingItemAtURL: NSURL; toURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; removingItemAtPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldProceedAfterError: NSError; removingItemAtURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldRemoveItemAtPath: NSString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager; shouldRemoveItemAtURL: NSURL): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    procedure fileManager(fm: NSFileManager; willProcessPath: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure finalize; cdecl;
    procedure forwardInvocation(anInvocation: NSInvocation); cdecl;
    function forwardingTargetForSelector(aSelector: SEL): Pointer; cdecl;
    procedure handleMachMessage(msg: Pointer); cdecl;
    procedure handlePortMessage(message: NSPortMessage); cdecl;
    function hash: NSUInteger; cdecl;
    function init: Pointer; cdecl;
    function initWithCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder): Pointer; cdecl;
    function isContentDiscarded: Boolean; cdecl;
    function isEqual(object_: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl;
    function isKindOfClass(aClass: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl;
    function isMemberOfClass(aClass: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl;
    function isProxy: Boolean; cdecl;
    procedure lock; cdecl;
    function metadataQuery(query: NSMetadataQuery; replacementObjectForResultObject: NSMetadataItem): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    function metadataQuery(query: NSMetadataQuery; replacementValueForAttribute: NSString; value: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    function methodForSelector(aSelector: SEL): IMP; cdecl;
    function methodSignatureForSelector(aSelector: SEL): NSMethodSignature; cdecl;
    function mutableArrayValueForKey(key: NSString): NSMutableArray; cdecl;
    function mutableArrayValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString): NSMutableArray; cdecl;
    function mutableCopy: Pointer; cdecl;
    function mutableCopyWithZone(zone: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    function mutableOrderedSetValueForKey(key: NSString): NSMutableOrderedSet; cdecl;
    function mutableOrderedSetValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString): NSMutableOrderedSet; cdecl;
    function mutableSetValueForKey(key: NSString): NSMutableSet; cdecl;
    function mutableSetValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString): NSMutableSet; cdecl;
    procedure netService(sender: NSNetService; didNotPublish: NSDictionary); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netService(sender: NSNetService; didNotResolve: NSDictionary); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netService(sender: NSNetService; didUpdateTXTRecordData: NSData); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netServiceBrowser(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser; didFindDomain: NSString; moreComing: Boolean); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netServiceBrowser(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser; didFindService: NSNetService; moreComing: Boolean); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netServiceBrowser(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser; didNotSearch: NSDictionary); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netServiceBrowser(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser; didRemoveDomain: NSString; moreComing: Boolean); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netServiceBrowser(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser; didRemoveService: NSNetService; moreComing: Boolean); cdecl; overload;
    procedure netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser); cdecl;
    procedure netServiceBrowserWillSearch(aNetServiceBrowser: NSNetServiceBrowser); cdecl;
    procedure netServiceDidPublish(sender: NSNetService); cdecl;
    procedure netServiceDidResolveAddress(sender: NSNetService); cdecl;
    procedure netServiceDidStop(sender: NSNetService); cdecl;
    procedure netServiceWillPublish(sender: NSNetService); cdecl;
    procedure netServiceWillResolve(sender: NSNetService); cdecl;
    function observationInfo: Pointer; cdecl;
    procedure observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString; ofObject: Pointer; change: NSDictionary; context: Pointer); cdecl;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; didEndElement: NSString; namespaceURI: NSString; qualifiedName: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; didEndMappingPrefix: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; didStartElement: NSString; namespaceURI: NSString; qualifiedName: NSString; attributes: NSDictionary); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; didStartMappingPrefix: NSString; toURI: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundCDATA: NSData); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundCharacters: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundComment: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundElementDeclarationWithName: NSString; model: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundExternalEntityDeclarationWithName: NSString; publicID: NSString; systemID: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundIgnorableWhitespace: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundInternalEntityDeclarationWithName: NSString; value: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundNotationDeclarationWithName: NSString; publicID: NSString; systemID: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundProcessingInstructionWithTarget: NSString; data: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; foundUnparsedEntityDeclarationWithName: NSString; publicID: NSString; systemID: NSString; notationName: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; parseErrorOccurred: NSError); cdecl; overload;
    function parser(parser: NSXMLParser; resolveExternalEntityName: NSString; systemID: NSString): NSData; cdecl; overload;
    procedure parser(parser: NSXMLParser; validationErrorOccurred: NSError); cdecl; overload;
    procedure parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser); cdecl;
    procedure parserDidStartDocument(parser: NSXMLParser); cdecl;
    procedure performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl;
    function performSelector(aSelector: SEL): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    procedure performSelector(aSelector: SEL; onThread: NSThread; withObject: Pointer; waitUntilDone: Boolean); cdecl; overload;
    procedure performSelector(aSelector: SEL; onThread: NSThread; withObject: Pointer; waitUntilDone: Boolean; modes: NSArray); cdecl; overload;
    function performSelector(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    procedure performSelector(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer; afterDelay: NSTimeInterval); cdecl; overload;
    procedure performSelector(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer; afterDelay: NSTimeInterval; inModes: NSArray); cdecl; overload;
    procedure performSelectorInBackground(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer); cdecl;
    procedure performSelectorOnMainThread(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer; waitUntilDone: Boolean); cdecl; overload;
    procedure performSelectorOnMainThread(aSelector: SEL; withObject: Pointer; waitUntilDone: Boolean; modes: NSArray); cdecl; overload;
    procedure presentedItemDidChange; cdecl;
    procedure presentedItemDidGainVersion(version: NSFileVersion); cdecl;
    procedure presentedItemDidLoseVersion(version: NSFileVersion); cdecl;
    procedure presentedItemDidMoveToURL(newURL: NSURL); cdecl;
    procedure presentedItemDidResolveConflictVersion(version: NSFileVersion); cdecl;
    function presentedItemOperationQueue: NSOperationQueue; cdecl;
    function presentedItemURL: NSURL; cdecl;
    procedure presentedSubitemAtURL(url: NSURL; didGainVersion: NSFileVersion); cdecl; overload;
    procedure presentedSubitemAtURL(url: NSURL; didLoseVersion: NSFileVersion); cdecl; overload;
    procedure presentedSubitemAtURL(oldURL: NSURL; didMoveToURL: NSURL); cdecl; overload;
    procedure presentedSubitemAtURL(url: NSURL; didResolveConflictVersion: NSFileVersion); cdecl; overload;
    procedure presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL(url: NSURL); cdecl;
    procedure presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL(url: NSURL); cdecl;
    procedure rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge(challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl;
    procedure release; cdecl;
    procedure removeObserver(observer: NSObject; forKeyPath: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure removeObserver(observer: NSObject; forKeyPath: NSString; context: Pointer); cdecl; overload;
    function replacementObjectForCoder(aCoder: NSCoder): Pointer; cdecl;
    function replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver(archiver: NSKeyedArchiver): Pointer; cdecl;
    function respondsToSelector(aSelector: SEL): Boolean; cdecl;
    function retain: Pointer; cdecl;
    function retainCount: NSUInteger; cdecl;
    function roundingMode: NSRoundingMode; cdecl;
    function scale: Smallint; cdecl;
    function self: Pointer; cdecl;
    procedure setNilValueForKey(key: NSString); cdecl;
    procedure setObservationInfo(observationInfo: Pointer); cdecl;
    procedure setValue(value: Pointer; forKey: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure setValue(value: Pointer; forKeyPath: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure setValue(value: Pointer; forUndefinedKey: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(keyedValues: NSDictionary); cdecl;
    procedure stream(aStream: NSStream; handleEvent: NSStreamEvent); cdecl;
    function unarchiver(unarchiver: NSKeyedUnarchiver; didDecodeObject: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl; overload;
    procedure unarchiver(unarchiver: NSKeyedUnarchiver; willReplaceObject: Pointer; withObject: Pointer); cdecl; overload;
    procedure unarchiverDidFinish(unarchiver: NSKeyedUnarchiver); cdecl;
    procedure unarchiverWillFinish(unarchiver: NSKeyedUnarchiver); cdecl;
    procedure unlock; cdecl;
    procedure useCredential(credential: NSURLCredential; forAuthenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge); cdecl;
    function validateValue(ioValue: Pointer; forKey: NSString; error: PPointer): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function validateValue(ioValue: Pointer; forKeyPath: NSString; error: PPointer): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    function valueForKey(key: NSString): Pointer; cdecl;
    function valueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString): Pointer; cdecl;
    function valueForUndefinedKey(key: NSString): Pointer; cdecl;
    procedure willChange(changeKind: NSKeyValueChange; valuesAtIndexes: NSIndexSet; forKey: NSString); cdecl;
    procedure willChangeValueForKey(key: NSString); cdecl; overload;
    procedure willChangeValueForKey(key: NSString; withSetMutation: NSKeyValueSetMutationKind; usingObjects: NSSet); cdecl; overload;
    function zone: Pointer; cdecl;
  end;
  TNSObject = class(TOCGenericImport<NSObjectClass, NSObject>)  end;
*)
```

why ? some like addObserver are very useful ...

Comment: Why are you repeating the same statement over and over? What help is that?

Comment: @JerryDodge: because you was more faster than me to Edit the question and correct it :) i was in the process to remove it when you did it before me :)

Comment: Interfaces don't need to expose all possible members of the class it represents. Only the ones which you need. On the other hand, the same does not apply the other way around. If you have an interface, any object behind it *must* implement every member of that interface.

Comment: @JerryDodge: this i understand, but why delphi decide to hide such usefull function ?

Comment: Not sure, but it definitely looks like someone really re-wrote it. I mean, look at all those commented pieces, such as `{class}`. Perhaps it was made just for testing / experimentation, and the final product only exposed those members which were required to work. If that's what your question is, you'd be much better off asking the author of the code.

Comment: yes i see that, but i m sad that i must manually edit the delphi source file to add back such function :(

Comment: @loki2 Perhaps that's not the only solution - most likely you can wrap this yourself without using what comes with Delphi.

Comment: @JerryDodge: maybe but in the case of addObserver how to do so ?

Comment: maybe like this:   TNSNotificationCenter.Wrap(TNSNotificationCenter.OCClass.defaultCenter).addObserver(FOrientationListener.GetObjectID,
    sel_getUid('DeviceOrientationChanged'), StringToID('UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification'), nil); i will try

Comment: [The same problem exists in Delphi for Android](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12686), too. Delphi's `Jlang_Class` interface does not expose many of the methods that the `Java.lang.Class` class actually has. For whatever reason, it feels like Embarcadero likes to pick-and-choose what THEY want to implement for THEIR needs, not what USERS might need.